# pygame how to load windows cursors

Tags: load, cursor, pygame

i want to load some different cursors for the programm i am making but i can't find anyway to do it. i found a pygame page that says this:

pygame.cursor.load_xbm(cursorfile, maskfile)    (http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/cursors.html)

but i am trying to load a .cur file according to windows and i don't have a mask file either so i have not idea how i can load it propperly and can't find anything about it really.
I hope somebody can help me

Answer (score 1):

Try looking online for services that provide a conversion between .cur and .xbm files.

You can also use the `pygame.cursors.compile` to hand create your cursor using strings (it may seem tedious but you only need a few pixels for a cursor image)

As well, you can also hide the mouse using `pygame.mouse.set_visible` and blit the cursor where the mouse is.